# Do you employ any tools for managing technical debt?

Tags: resources, bug-tracking, technical-debt

The site I work with on a day-to-day basis has its share of shortcomings and we often make design decisions to "get us by right now" with the intention of fixing those up later.

I've found that making the time to actually go back and fix them, let alone remembering what the full list of to-do items is can be challenging at best.

Can you recommend any tools, resources or tricks that help you effectively manage your technical debt?

Comment: leave a dead rat under the desk every time you leave some debt in the code base.

Comment: @skaffman, you misinterpreted "code smell" definition :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any bug/task tracking software, eg see this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool.

Of course, a simple solution is just to have a text file called TODO or similar. It's low maintenance, and particularly appropriate if it's a WORN file (write once, read never).

Answer (score 0):

- Unit testing
- Refactoring
- Continuous Integration
- Planning (XP, Kanban, etc.) to avoid adding more technical debt
- Standards
- Code reviews
- Project retrospectives
- Static analysis tools (like FxCop) integrated with the CI build or check in process

I'd say TODO comments in the code, but my experience has been that developers generally ignore these.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add an item in your product backlog whenever you deliberately incur technical debt. This way, it is possible to consciously spend time during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plug-in for Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/evaluate-your-technical-debt-with-sonar/) that you can use to find potential problems in your code base.

/Roger